# SAML bearer flow for retrieving an OAuth token gives an assertion error

Tags: apex, api, oauth2, saml

i'm posting the following request; trying to get an OAuth token:

```
POST /services/oauth2/token?grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Asaml2-bearer&assertion=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 HTTP/1.1
Host: login.salesforce.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 0
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

The unencoded SAML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<saml:Assertion xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="C625490D-C2B9-15BE-6DFA-7286288D9655" IssueInstant="2013-09-11T12:03:14Z" Version="2.0">
  <saml:Issuer>3MVGsVZJwhslq1dMKw0yQhJniL9S5PBIUNkJOF.1G4167JRtA5.YKjy76e84L_Si</saml:Issuer>
  <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <ds:SignedInfo>
      <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
      <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
      <ds:Reference URI="#C625490D-C2B9-15BE-6DFA-7286288D9655">
        <ds:Transforms>
          <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
          <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
        </ds:Transforms>
        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
        <ds:DigestValue>f187DeCiwFhhH2etlU+5byskey4=</ds:DigestValue>
      </ds:Reference>
    </ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:SignatureValue/>
  </ds:Signature>
  <saml:Subject>
    <saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified">myuser@mycompany.com.dev</saml:NameID>
    <saml:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
      <saml:SubjectConfirmationData Recipient="https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token" NotOnOrAfter="2013-09-11T13:03:14Z"/>
    </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
  </saml:Subject>
  <saml:Conditions NotBefore="2013-09-11T12:03:14Z" NotOnOrAfter="2013-09-11T13:03:14Z">
    <saml:AudienceRestriction>
      <saml:Audience><![CDATA[https://login.salesforce.com]]></saml:Audience>
    </saml:AudienceRestriction>
  </saml:Conditions>
  <saml:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2013-09-11T06:54:14Z" SessionIndex="ED868FE5-841D-5192-766C-941A60D6602F">
    <saml:AuthnContext>
      <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:unspecified</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
    </saml:AuthnContext>
  </saml:AuthnStatement>
</saml:Assertion>
```

..and i'm getting this (500) error back:
    **Unable to Access Page**
    The value of the "assertion" parameter contains a character that is not allowed or the value exceeds the maximum allowed length. Remove the character from the parameter value or reduce the value length and resubmit. If the error still persists, report it to our Customer Support team. Provide the URL of the page you were requesting as well as any other related information.

So, I narrow it down to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<saml:Assertion xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
  <saml:Issuer>3MqushJniL9S5PBIUNkd68PvmYsLF.1G417JRtA5.YKjy_Si</saml:Issuer>
  <saml:Subject>
  </saml:Subject>
</saml:Assertion>
```

which fails with a (400) invalid assertion error. So my assumption is that the above parses correctly, but is missing info.
Adding the NameID attribute (even empty):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<saml:Assertion xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
  <saml:Issuer>3MqushJniL9S5PBIUNkd68PvmYsLF.1G417JRtA5.YKjy_Si</saml:Issuer>
  <saml:Subject>
    <saml:NameID/>
  </saml:Subject>
</saml:Assertion>
```

causes it to revert back to the 500 error. Unfortunately the error message does not tell me what exactly is the problem area, and as far as i can tell, my XML is to spec. How do I get a lead on what's happening?

~gilbert

Comment: hey Gilbert, did you get solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

When there is an encoding issue, Salesforce will not be able to understand the assertion and will respond with {'error_description':'invalid assertion','error':'invalid_grant'}.

As per the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_SAML_bearer_flow.htm&type=5),  when posted to the token endpoint, the assertion must be encoded using base64url encoding as defined here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#page-7

I have seen such issues in the past and it happens when the assertion is not encoded properly. An example is base64 encoding and then URL encoding, which isn't the same as base64url encoding as per specification https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#page-7 (see section 5 "Base 64 Encoding with URL and Filename Safe Alphabet")

i.e. base64url encoding replaces + with - (minus) instead of %2B (base64 62nd character)

As an example of the correct encoding, you can try this online tool: http://kjur.github.io/jsjws/tool_b64uenc.html

If you have already applied base64url encoding for the assertion and getting a generic "Invalid assertion", I recommend taking a look at [Error 'Invalid assertion' in OAuth 2.0 SAML Bearer Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000334987&type=1&mode=1)

**SAML Bearer Flow troubleshooting**

1. Verify that XML document has  : Salesforce supports only UTF-8 encoding. UTF-16 will cause a problem.
2. Make sure that when POSTed to the token endpoint, the assertion must be encoded using base64url encoding . Base64url encoding is different from base64 encoding" + url encoding. Base64url encoding replaces + with - (minus) instead of %2B.

Answer (score 0):

Just Check whether the SAML is base64 encoded.If its not encoded then use the below mentioned URL for encoding it.

https://fed-lab.org/simplesaml-register/module.php/saml2debug/debug.php